# Watchservice not being triggered

Tags: java, watchservice

I'm writing an application in which I'm monitoring a log file from an external program using the WatchService (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html).
Whenever an EVENT_MODIFIED is triggered on the file , I read it and check if a certain string is present.
My program works fine when I manually enter text and save the file, but when the log file is edited by the external program, the WatchService is not triggered.

I've tried a different approach where I use a thread in which I read the file and sleep for a certain amount of time and then repeat. This does the trick, but I'd rather not poll the file every X seconds when it should be possible to just "listen" for the changes.

Does anyone know why the WatchServices is not detecting these modifications?

Comment: OS? Filesystem? Java Version?

Comment: Windows 7, NTFS, Java 1.7

Comment: When you edit a file and save it by hand, does the problem still occur? Have you tried it with JDK8? And maybe on another OS like Debian ;)?

Comment: As stated in my original post, when I manually enter something and save the file, the WatchService does get triggered :)
I will try with JDK 8 and on my Ubuntu installation, but it is my intention to run the program on Windows.

Comment: I as linux friend and user know that especially for ext systems you have mount options where the modification time can be ignored (often just m_time) - I don't know how that is handled in Windows but maybe that is a hint to look for. I also experienced some buggy behaviour in OS X a year ago. Anyway it could be a very platform dependent problem.

Comment: @Girmi the problem is similar to the one posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306875/watchservice-in-windows-7-does-not-work