# Which Operating Systems support native (inotify-like) file watching in Java

Tags: java, linux, java-8, raspberry-pi, inotify

The JavaDoc for `java.nio.file.WatchService` states;

> The implementation ... is
>   intended to map directly on to the **native file event notification
>   facility** where available, or to use a primitive mechanism, such as
>   polling, when a native facility is not available.

I assume this means it will try a lightweight, native mechanism when it can (something like `inotify` on Linux) and poll if it can not.

Is that correct?

What operating systems are likely or unlikely to provide such a facility? Distro level for Linux would be really useful or can I assume that if the JVM runs on *unix, it will be supported?

Comment: this is not ona ya question of OS, but of the filesystem as well. If you are running your app in a docker container inotify is not able to watch overlay filesystem directories.

Answer (score 7):

This should have probably been a comment, but it's too big to post it as such...

I am looking at `jdk-9` sources (could easily be searched in the jdk-8 repo as well), but here is some relevant to your question comments:

```
   /**
     * Linux implementation of WatchService based on inotify.
     *
     * In summary a background thread polls inotify plus a socket used for the wakeup
     * mechanism. Requests to add or remove a watch, or close the watch service,
     * cause the thread to wakeup and process the request. Events are processed
     * by the thread which causes it to signal/queue the corresponding watch keys.
     */

 class LinuxWatchService  extends AbstractWatchService
```

And for windows:

```
/*
 * Win32 implementation of WatchService based on ReadDirectoryChangesW.
 */

class WindowsWatchService extends AbstractWatchService
```

And so on.. you can find all the available implementations under:

```
 jdk/src/java.base/{windows|unix|solaris|linux...}/classes/sun/nio/fs/
```

As what OS actually supports this, it seems like that would require for you to look at the actual distro.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can find some information in this post [Watchservice in windows 7 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306875/watchservice-in-windows-7-does-not-work). There is some note about file system watchers on Windows and MacOSX (author of post says that they are using polling).
On Linux file system monitoring is part of a Linux kernel and it's implemented using quite nice notifications mechanism (more info about some of them can be found [here](http://www.lanedo.com/filesystem-monitoring-linux-kernel/))