# What filesystems have native support for file change notification? (java watchservice)

Tags: java, event-handling, polling, watchservice

I am using a java watchservice to monitor a file that could be on different filesystems. how do i know that the watchservice can actually dock onto the filesystems notification system or does actually revert to classic polling(which i completely want to avoid)?

Comment: This doesn't actually answer your question, but have you read this (similar) question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141838/which-operating-systems-support-native-inotify-like-file-watching-in-java)? maybe it is a start?