# Gracefully shutting down jvm when a jar file gets removed

Tags: java, jvm

`System.getProperty("java.class.path")` returns list of jar files that a java process uses. I have a server process that needs to shut down gracefully when any of those jar files get removed. Server has a watchdog thread that can shutdown the process if any of the jar files get removed.

My question is related to how to find if any jar was removed (deleted / changed permission) or not.

One approach to find if any jar was removed is to periodically check if File.exists returns true or not for each one of the jar files.

Is there any support by jvm to get this information without manually checking file status every time? What is the best way to detect whether all jar files are intact or not?

Thanks.

Comment: This may be a place to start:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141838/which-operating-systems-support-native-inotify-like-file-watching-in-java

Comment: You are describing two steps – 1. notice that a file has been moved, and 2. stop the JVM. Step 1 can run in your Java app, or externally (various scripting choices). Step 2 can also be triggered from your Java app or externally (by sending a signal to a running JVM).

Comment: Interested in step 1 only that you mentioned, @kaan

Comment: If you don’t want to use WatchService, there’s nothing wrong with polling for each file’s existence, unless you need to be notified immediately of the file’s removal.  Note that it’s not normal to remove .jar files which are in the classpath.  It may not even be possible in Windows.  I know the Java process used to lock such files;  I’m not sure if it still does.

Comment: On my system, I can’t remove a jar file while a JVM process using it in the class path is running… If you want to keep up with the future (which is already there), you have to be aware that there’s also a module-path potentially containing jar files. And removing a jar file containing code needed for the shutdown (and not loaded yet) may always prevent a graceful shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature within the VM to specifically watch the jars on the classpath, no; you must program this up yourself by gathering the jar files from the j.c.p property and using the [`WatchService`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141838/which-operating-systems-support-native-inotify-like-file-watching-in-java) to watch for these.

Comment: But you can take the directory part of the JARs in the classpath and create ```WatcherService```s for each of them. Then, on an event, you can check if the file name (on which the event occurred) is a classpath entry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample code that does what @rzwitserloop pointed out. The sample code is based on the sample provided at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html. You will need to do a performance test for the case of watching multiple folders and when multiple events are being raised.

```
public class CPChangeListeningJava{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        /* Store the classpath to check against during an event. */
        String cp = System.getProperty( "java.class.path" );

        /* For every unique directory in the classpath, create a WatchService. (Only one case shown here.) */
        try{
            WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

            String dirStr = "C:\\SKN\\Workspaces\\General\\ctools\\target"; //One of the paths in the classpath
            Path dir = Paths.get( dirStr );
            try{
                WatchKey key = dir.register( watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY );

                while( true ){
                    try{
                        key = watcher.take();
                    }
                    catch( InterruptedException x ){
                        return;
                    }

                    for( WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents() ){
                        WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

                        if( kind == OVERFLOW ){
                            continue;
                        }

                        // The filename is the context of the event.
                        WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                        Path filename = ev.context();

                        /* If the file is present in the classpath, process it. */
                        String fullFilePath = dirStr + "\\" + filename; //You may want to check based on Path instances
                        if( cp.contains( fullFilePath ) ) System.out.println( filename + ": " + ev.kind() );
                    }

                    /* Reset the key to receive further watch events. */
                    boolean valid = key.reset();
                    if( !valid ) break;
                }
            }
            catch( IOException x ){
                System.err.println( x );
            }
        }
        catch( IOException e ){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```